# Using get_the_excerpt($id) inside loop returns the current page excerpt

Tags: wordpress

Something I've noticed, that I don't think I'm doing wrong, but this isn't working as expected.

Generally, when using `get_the_excerpt()`, you can pass a post ID when outside the loop.

However, I would assume that if I use this function INSIDE the loop, but supply the ID to whatever page I want, it would return the excerpt for that post ID.

However, all that is returned is the current post (as I'm in the loop). But surely this isn't expected behaviour?

If I'm inside the loop

Comment: have you a full code example to help you ?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt#Usage explains a scenario in which this could be problematic, check if that is somehow related to what you’re doing.

Comment: Supply the code for your loop and we might be able to help! For example, it's amazing how many people think that a `get_posts()` followed by a `foreach` is a loop. It is, but it's not a Loop in WordPress terms.

Comment: @PeterHvD I know what the Wordpress loop is, but actually I've just worked out I'm outside of the loop, as `the_post()` returns null just before the call. However, `get_the_excerpt($id)` is still returning the excerpt of the current page I'm looking at, not the ID i want.  This seems like a wordpress bug.

Comment: Post your code and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking into wp_trim_excerpt function, which filters the get_the_excerpt

```
function wp_trim_excerpt( $text = '' ) {
    $raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content('');

        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

        /**
         * Filters the number of words in an excerpt.
         *
         * @since 2.7.0
         *
         * @param int $number The number of words. Default 55.
         */
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters( 'excerpt_length', 55 );
        /**
         * Filters the string in the "more" link displayed after a trimmed excerpt.
         *
         * @since 2.9.0
         *
         * @param string $more_string The string shown within the more link.
         */
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters( 'excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]' );
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    /**
     * Filters the trimmed excerpt string.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     *
     * @param string $text        The trimmed text.
     * @param string $raw_excerpt The text prior to trimming.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt );
}
```

The $text here equals to the $post->post_excerpt, if it's empty it uses get_the_content()

So the answer here is either to fill the custom excerpt field or do something like this

```
function custom_excerpt($text, $post = '') {

  if ( '' == $text ) {

    if ( !empty($post) ) {
      $text = $post->post_content;
    } else {
      $text = get_the_content('');
    }

    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

    /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
    $text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

    /**
     * Filters the number of words in an excerpt.
     *
     * @since 2.7.0
     *
     * @param int $number The number of words. Default 55.
     */
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters( 'excerpt_length', 55 );
    /**
     * Filters the string in the "more" link displayed after a trimmed excerpt.
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param string $more_string The string shown within the more link.
     */
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters( 'excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]' );
    $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );

    return $text;
  } 

  return $text;
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt', 10, 2);
```